# Generation of Test Cases

Tags: java

I need to generate the test cases using white box testing..
I would like to share my idea of what we are doing and would also like you to give suggestions on it, if any, if we are going wrong.
As Netbeans and eclipse are having their own editors for writing java programs n then compile and generate test cases for the same..
But our aim is to create the application that accepts i.e reads java program written anywherei.e like notepad,command prompt i.e stored anywhere but should be .java file to be read by our application and our application should on reading the .java file should be directly able to generate the test cases for it.

What we have done is created some grammars for control statements i.e., for,if,switch,etc, have parsed the java file into tokens,and we are now in a process to create the symbol table to retrieve the symbols from user's java file consisting of symbol name,its length,value,data type.But we are stuck here..
Its getting difficult to retrieve symbols,its value and data type from java file..

Everything is coded in java,and no tool is used.Please provide some solution.

Comment: Can you give an example of the sort of test cases you will be able to generate?  Most static analysis tools will detect bugs just by reading the code. Not sure what you can do in unit tests which this cannot do.

Comment: "No tool is used" -- have you considered using a tool to assist with parsing -- say, like ANTLR?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, this boils down to whether it's possible to generate test cases based on source code, and if so, how to do that. The short answer is that it's not. You can generate something, but it won't be testing anything useful. You should be designing test cases based on your requirements/specification, not your code.

Think of it this way: if your tests are based on the code, they have no frame of reference for what is correct or incorrect. As a result, the most they will be able to do is faithfully confirm that your code does whatever it is that your code does; they won't be able to compare to what the code is *supposed* to do.